# On React Flux, where I am supposed to populate the initial state of my Stores?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm studying Flux and I think I understood the workflow:

```
View -> Action -> Dispatcher -> Store -> View
```

However, I didn't quite understand where am I supposed to populate the initial state of my Stores.

For instance, let's say that I'm editing a Contact. So I'd assume I'd have a `ContactsStore`. This is what I imagine would happen when I access the URL `/contacts/edit/23`:

1. Somehow my `ContactsStore` gets populated with the contact I'm editing, in this case, contact 23. The data would come from the server.
2. The `EditContact` view would receive a notification from the `ContactsStore`, so it would render itself in the initial state.
3. As I save the contact, the view would trigger the `SaveContact` action and the flow would go on.

Step (1) is not clear to me. Where is the `ContactsStore` expected to be populated with the initial state? Where do I call the server? Is it on the Store?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have access to the action and the store in your `EditContact` component. In the `componentDidMount` handler you could fire an action which does the api request. On success it passes the contact to the `dispatcher`/`store`. As soon as the store receives the `contact` it fires an event on which the `EditContact` component has subscribed. In the corresponding handler the component sets the new state with the new contact. I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 3):

The way I, and I think many others, do it is I trigger an action from the view to load the contact. Let's call it `LOAD_CONTACT`. This would be an asynchronous action. Some people put the API call in the store directly, but I think it's more common to do async work in the action creators. So let's say you have an action creator `loadContactAction()`. Then that would first dispatch the `LOAD_CONTACT` action (just in case some store might be interested in this, for displaying a "loading" message or something), then fetch from the API. In the callback of the ajax request, you call another action creator, e.g. `loadContactSuccessAction()` (or "failed", of course). Your `ContactsStore` store then registers and reacts to `LOAD_CONTACT_SUCCESSFUL`.

```
var loadContactAction = function(...) {
    // maybe do some work
    dispatch(...); // dispatch your LOAD_CONTACT action

    makeRequest(...).then(function(contact) {
        loadContactSuccessAction(contact); // create "success" action
    }, function(err) {
        loadContactFailedAction(err); // probably handle this somewhere
    });
}

var ContactsStore = {
    init(...) {
        // register in dispatcher here
    },
    onLoadContactSuccess(contact) {
        this.contacts[contact.id] = contact; // or store your contact some other way
        this.emitChange(); // trigger a store update change event with whatever event dispatcher you use
    }
}

var EditContact = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        ContactsStore.listen(this.onStoreChange);
        loadContactAction(); // pass in ID or however you want to load it
    },
    onStoreChange: function() {
        // fetch your contact here
    },
    render: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Florian Gl answer
though i would recommend reading the article below, about higher order components, you should leave the logic out of your component, and use a higher order component that passed the data as props, avoid using state as much as possible , it will only add extra complexity

in Your higherlevel component(container): componentWillMount handler you can  fire an action which does the api request, on success this state is saved to the store, and as soon as the store receives the contact it fires an event on which the EditContact component Container has subscribed -> which is passed to the editContact component

State should live in your store:)

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750

Answer (score 0):

When you're constructing the initial state of your app, you should fire an action to fetch the data for "contact 23". That action makes an asynchronous call, which results in an event, which populates a store, which a component uses to get its state.

However, do you want to put the logic that fires the action in that component? Not necessarily. Are you using any routing libraries? If so, they are likely the best place from which to trigger the action.

For example, using [fluxible-router](https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible-router), its [routing configuration](https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/blob/master/fluxible-router%2Fconfigs%2Froutes.js) allows you to specify that each route (e.g. `/contacts/23`) should fire an action.

This lets you decouple how to *display* data from how to *retrieve* it. You could use the same component and have it get its data from AJAX in one case, from local storage in another case, etc. You could also optimize the fetching of data, e.g. by bundling together multiple calls, without having to change any components.